# Replace image in email via embedded body part pointed to content-id

Tags: php, image, email, base64, imap

I want my email to properly display image.

I manage to fetched email via:

```
$hostname = '{mail.domain.com:143/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX';

$username = "*****";

$password = "*****";

$inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect : ' . 

imap_last_error());

$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, 4, 1.2);
```

The result shows everything except images.
The image show scr="cid:profilephoto" which mean its pointed to an embedded image somewhere on the same page but since the imap_fetchbody only show a certain part of message body so i couldn't tell where is the image.

```
  <img src="cid:profilephoto" width="27" height="27">
```

when I set the imap_fetchbody number to 2:

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, 4, 2);
```

Then it show the image part but only the base64 coded image and not other HTML.

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHQAAAApCAMAAADTVP08AAAC6FBMVEUAAAAPY+IVZ+QOYN0PZ+cV auvPNycPX98PZOkPY+fURjPSPCn/swD/rwAabObfTz8Taesdce8PZOX0qwD/tQDcUj8Taev/rwDJ OSb/rwAVauwPZecPZOUPZOTUPyrGNyXPPy/YQi8bb+vxrQD/vBXRQCrPOyfXRS/PLx8ab+/XRzHf VUEfb+8TZuIAj0fMNyfWQivVQSwOY+QUZeD/tQEZb+0Aj0UUauvRPSf/tAAZb+3ZRTEQYuD/vw/E NyUPZuUUa+zJNSX/tQETZ+YcbekGol/MPisGoFzPPirVUD7XQy8UZuEAj0oab+/ROygVZ+ISaOr5 twjNOSfgV0UZaeP/vA3VUD7bUj7YSDTfTz//uQ/aRjHxthMRYt0ece//wBXfUT8ccu8fbePZTzoJ pWEHn18Aj0v/tgDLPSgAjUr/tgQAj0sQYdwAj08AkU0PY+P/twv5rwD0tRf/uQv/uBP/vRQNXtnX Tzv/uQUTZN/ZTDrXRy//swD0tAPaTjrQPCfeVUPgVEL5vRPNOifcVELXRzPcSzj/sgATZugWbOsh cu8XbO4Wa+wab+8QZObWQSsSZ+kUaevYQi3/swAVauwRZ+gYbe4gc/Adce8ecvAcce8TaerTPirU PyrRPSnbRTEAnlkAkUzZRC8QZecRZujZSjUZbu7XRzIRZucAnFgAm1jPPCkidPAAmFYZbu//tAEQ YNvcSDXaTTj/vxXdSjcPYNvfTToZaeAPXtjbRzPCNyUWZt/iVkXhU0EfbeEUZd//tgD/uQvIPCcA llUIpGDfVkQbauHvtRD/wA7gUD3/uADJPivNQS7wqADZRjEAlFAAmlcSY97/uw//tQMCoFv/vAbd VUIAl1bOOij/vBP/twb/vgkAlVP/twgRYdzcUT3vpwDvsBLMQi7DNyXQTTzTTz7SSjkDol3/twD/ wBoJpWEGo17/uwPSUUDNSTbNSjfvqgDGPCbwrArPTz3UUEDwtA8ebOEea+HIBunwAAAAi3RSTlMA uNDQII8gEDBA0FBAENAQgHBw0FBgoTDQIGCAoWAw0BBQQOhguEBgEGCAgDDQQGBwoY/ooaEwoWBg gI/QEOhQcDCPuLhQ6NDQ0EDoYDBw0HC4j4/oYOihcCAwoejooY9wUOgwoWCAcOi4cEDoEHCAQLjQ gFCh6EAw6LhAcNChj4+huKG4QHChUFChsR1CegAABXFJREFUeF7FlWVw21gQx9eJHclhbhpo06SQ ppwyM8OV4dorHDMzM0lmdpiZmbHMzAzHTF9vnyxZieecm5uMc78va/1nnn6z73mf4H9m9YxFvrWK nFa3hf4x0C9QAX9ZzGarQpFjNDIMezJUCn3k4W+Rrq7F4JQ9LSbTvoDVgEjDFzIsq9eEUtAXFi9d isquR5y3+WVRUUuAGNBvoFRTBn3kO8S580FTUcvoHlGoXnOSdql0p8n0p+AU0PfdCV8h4IQAi8US 4Bhyzr5LzzhxSmvNln3gCA195wziRDrZajaPBFeAzjQnA1qrsFop10jT0pxIRyoUio3QKw9t2Lx3 77lzy0P8QOT+XTu+QV4cOlvMYnbus90vDMPIANJE6bYNP+ArftvyGnDIShSKydALfh833X0/JGTL 9evXfxoihLM/rNy/a+jQVyorK2++zGeUr8my0bfWJp0KRJqfDxyjmvYuHzXqDr4iHghuOTklM3pr 8/emzX7cjx8rKrJH8G3ur9wxm/tx8+LFi5v4aS9qicEiU5QYV1KA5OfnFwDhg6bmEFLfraio2MpJ jcacXqR+d5vv+PH67Ozs3BWA+Ow/8IcPrz+FPA/IoqKikUCYgZ1O5KQFBZx0d3PzbuDwzM6+FU2k DGOUgVPePHgwRAjic3NzDwOy7sCBTUL40qn29l+xjjaZTHzUitsbjrWg4MQJLH73Dt7jBTPxDWSz 7sNDd3O+uTU1NduEIDojI0PrBfD65cuXBwqhTzsSjP2ZTL58FM6f6QkEy6c1NZ5AeGv7sWPDhgAv bQRnzKyqqhKDYVqVagLAApSK4bqrV69OAvC12K8YCqVjRKlnVRVKo7ceOXY43gM4ZCzLMDR0g76W mKhWqw2GrLngWV5eLkrHq1TJcwDeOXv2rBg+eenSpViUmi1mIVopSIuLsRwpL/f8ZHt9KjYpEM4i PQ5VMgtBaVYUQGp9fX00CAxXJSelAHyP+ICA92kEYJHZbN3DR24M64+luLj4PJZUwhFsUkSqR05S 4AA68/gFK8Q0OUmQeovh6dOlpQABVqt93icyrBTL+fOdnVhuoXME9GShBq3+4IAhi5MuyUhNHd9d mjIYIPbQoUOPiWFpaWkQd50qFDG2Phjb1nUiWJbh/89RKtcQaIcUnZlYJuCCJWKKja4HmITSWDHU 6XQLuPu0pKSRBtRPZKcCL71C5kSr1R4GBySJyAMOG4xOIh2iReyn4ZGUUjgfIPhrxD4zA1E6AJDw RqOxUfaFfys7DziuIFgGaZHxDlLq2j9Y0Umk8DhKJwjhtJTCwaTGonSSEE7X6YKAQzrPza2VYQSn IIVlKpWqY5CDlSZW9dM9dhidSlIHqRAv4Ii7XdjAdT2gDQkGDp+juhsDwY6MYVngOY7Y39HhJYyA YC1TEyKo7lKl0tadfUFcWGHDfL47lP7MWX2CdDcGgMgYVq9fCxzPCFKYlowkhXnFgce4OeOAh5IQ qaE6cq6UPMkDJUqEH85fcEXYGq/3GgoH20/X+2hbmy7o7eAFN3RB2KeIv16v0cgoQJ49np6e/sSj YzH16kjCYUspvHChAZ125BK8gZC8PDxN0uarz8ntRzmMrLj90XDoxvQXdMjRz7y7h1K5P05CYmIZ DbAq3cYqQOLWhBHlnPUe0AMqKtKdU7q7JwTK4b8jDy3TECWirqZhylNjCVPAhdBjNJrQzykM1pKb u5oC14MTcI0W/NX4tYgAl0NmXS4+VRuy3MHlRKjVZSAyNyuvDlwOfgpn9bzQ3PtBajAYKDGQZmYm gMuR4IhHdHvMVErB5cjzkEA+oCKVyijoByIzkbpAOZJQ1z9OJLCOaJUc7jS4HPEarUOhJPBfj/Nv 9fJre47yRD8AAAAASUVORK5CYII
```

How do I set embedded image for this element to point at?

Please no PHPmailer or Swiftmailer library or any other library.

Comment: Its not duplicate. Questions ask on how to embed image when received email, not how to handle base64 image or send image in email. @showdev

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem.

```
function mime($x,$y,$z){
$a=array();
$b='Content-';
$c=explode($b,trim(str_replace(array('<','>'),"",(imap_fetchmime($x,$y,$z,FT_UID|FT_PEEK))),$b));

        if($c!=""){

                for($n=0;$n<count($c);$n++){

                    if($c[$n]!=""){       
                        $d=explode(':',$c[$n]);
                        $a[strtolower($d[0])]=$d[1];
                    }
                }
         }

 return $a;
}
```

Function above help me to:

- Identify mime info for specific part/body of multi-part email.
- List item in array for reference.

How to use it?

```
$set=mime($inbox,4,1); // Connection, msgid, part/body section
```

Output reference:

```
$set['type'];
$set['disposition'];
$set['transfer-encoding'];
$set['id'];
```

With reference id given by $set['id'] , you can search in the message body for src="cid:[id]" and change the src value with the base64 image.